# c++ class templating ( with defaults )

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do something like this. but cannot figure out the right syntax .. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
template <typename T, typename K = UINT32>
class info
{
   K* asArray();
}

template <typename T, typename K = UINT32>
K* info<T, UINT32>:: asArray() { // return a int array };

template <typename T, char>
char* info<T, char>:: asArray() { // return a char array };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need - put the definition into the class template.

```
template <typename T, typename K = int>
class info {
  K* asArray(){ return 0; }
};
```

A specialisation of the class member alone is possible via e.g.

```
template<>
char* info<int,char>::asArray(){ return new char[10]; }
```

This overrides the basic definition in the class template:

```
info<int,char> iv;
char* iptr = iv.asArray();
if( iptr != 0 ) std::cout << "ok - not null" << std::endl;
```

Displays `ok - not null`.

Comment: And what about member specialization?

Comment: @Constructor Added the *full specialisation*. (But I didn't realize that this is what OP was driving at.)

Comment: Obviously OP's question was about a *partial* specialization of a class template member.

Comment: @Constructor Inventing non-existent syntax to ask a question is, perhaps, not the best way.

Comment: It is a usual way to formulate the problem.

Comment: @Constructor s/usual/obfuscating/ ;-) OK, I might have tried to outguess. But it gets tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a partial specialization of a member function only. You have to create a specialization of the class itself.

```
template <typename T>
class info<T, char>
{
   char* asArray();
};
```

Then, you can use:

```
template <typename T>
char* info<T, char> asArray  { // return a char array }
```

This is not allowed:

```
template <typename T, typename K = UINT32>
K* info<T, UINT32>:: asArray() { // return a int array };
```

You have to use:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
K* info<T, K>:: asArray() { // return a K array };
```

Comment: Of course you can. But only an explicit (=full) specialization, not a partial one.

Comment: @Constructor Learned something today. Thanks for your input. I updated the answer to reflect that.